# latencySmoothFactor equivalence in mongo driver 2.12.0

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

The MongoEnvironmentSetter#setLatencySmoothFactor method updates the system property *com.mongodb.latencySmoothFactor* and it isn't available since 2.12.0 ( related git hashes [0375c984fccf9cb0868b406c145f8fd3e263348c](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/commit/0375c984fccf9cb0868b406c145f8fd3e263348c) [1ae976fa2342cdddeade622f293dc3fccbb80a58](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/commit/1ae976fa2342cdddeade622f293dc3fccbb80a58)). I found the following tickets related to that:

- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-763
- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-786
- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-859
- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-930
- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-931

But I didn't find the equivalence to this property. Any thoughts? Which are the steps to do in a migration if some application has configured this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent in 2.12, as the driver no longer performs any smoothing of round-trip times. Smoothing may be added in a future release, but most likely it won't be configurable.  I'm not sure what the MongoEnvironmentSetter is, but assuming this is something you control, your best option is to ignore that property or remove it.